# Error in VBA/Excel in simple command

Tags: vba

I did not use VBA for a while and I have an error 1004 when using this very simple command. I don't know what I have wrong there as it is very basic. (the range "start" is defined in the sheet "Output")

thanks a lot for your help

```
Sub simple()
    Dim under_unit As Variant
    under_unit = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("start").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error of the text message?

Comment: Are you sure the named range is in the worksheet scope and not the workbook scope?

Answer (score 0):

'make sure you have named the cell as: start; and the tab as: Output

```
Sub simple()

    Dim under_unit As Range
    Set under_unit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("start")

    under_unit.Value = "solved"

End Sub
```